# Samsung S3 will not get detected by computer

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, usb

I think my power plug is the problem. How can I make sure? PC's USB is working fine.

Comment: Have you installed [the USB driver](http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000117)?

Answer (score 0):

Download   USB Driver and Go to Device Manager->right click your device  ->select Update driver-> Select Browse from my Computer on diaglog->Browse the path where your USB Driver downloaded -> Click ok  or Select Browse from online it will take time but suitable driver will be install.

Answer (score 0):

If you think there is a problem with your cable, find a friend with a working cable and phone.

1. Try your friend's working cable with your phone. This should work.
2. Try the suspected bad cable with your friend's phone. This should not work.